# Galaxy Tab 10.1" 3G locked?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-10

I'm on vacation in the UK and the Galaxy Tab 10.1" is coming out here the first week of August. I was wondering if the tablet is locked to one of the networks here in the UK or if it's unlocked and I can essentially take it back to Canada or on the rest of my European travels and use on any 3G network with that counties providers?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get unlocked version, but most likely only from online stores just like [handtec](http://www.handtec.co.uk/product.php/4368/samsung-galaxy-tab-10-1--16gb--sim-free-unlocked-) (if admin feel this can be advertising please remove link)